# Mimik leveling algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm trying to mimik the leveling algorithm for Steam's leveling system.

Here are the level details:
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=457523080

> When you get started, each badge you craft will increase your level. Most badges give 100 XP, and it takes 100 XP to get to the next level. The amount needed to level up increases every 10 levels, meaning after Steam Level 10 you'll need 200XP per level, after level 20 you'll need 300XP per level, etc.

I've been trying to create a snippet of code that will return a list of this data programatically.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i <= 900; $i++ ) {

    // $i = level.        

    $xp_per_level = (ceil($i / 10) * 10) * 10;

    $xp = $i * $xp_per_level;

    echo 'Level: ' . $i . ' - XP Rate: ' . $xp_per_level . ' - XP: ' . number_format($xp) ;

    echo '<br />';
}
```

Output (Incorrect when compared with the level details provided above):

[image]

All the information it returns for the first 10 levels are correct but all after have the incorrect xp amount. I assume this is because the xp_per_level changes depending on the levels before.

Is there a way to solve this? I'm not hugely mathematical!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at e.g. the calculation for level 30.

```
$i = 30 ->  
$xp_per_level = (ceil(30 / 10) * 10) * 10; ->
$xp_per_level = 300
```

so far so good.... but now with `$xp = $i * $xp_per_level;` your code "assumes" that *each* level up to 30 also took 300xp -> wrong.
You can simply keep track of the previous XP needed to reach *this* level and then just add the XP needed for the next level, i.e. initialize `$xp=0;` before the loop and then `$xp += $xp_per_level;` within the loop.
But that kinda boring ;-)
Let's take a look at the XPs at the points where the XP per level change

```
Level    0 , XP:      0
Level   10 , XP:   1000
Level   20 , XP:   3000
Level   30 , XP:   6000
Level   40 , XP:  10000
Level   50 , XP:  15000
Level   60 , XP:  21000
Level   70 , XP:  28000
Level   80 , XP:  36000
Level   90 , XP:  45000
Level  100 , XP:  55000
```

Now let's try to figure out how 10 relates to 1000 like 20 to 3000 and so on.
Let's approach this straight forward

```
Level    0 , XP:      0
Level   10 , XP:   1000 =level*100
Level   20 , XP:   3000 =level *150
Level   30 , XP:   6000 =level *200  
Level   40 , XP:  10000 =level *250
Level   50 , XP:  15000 =level *300
Level   60 , XP:  21000 ...
Level   70 , XP:  28000 
Level   80 , XP:  36000 
Level   90 , XP:  45000 
Level  100 , XP:  55000
```

hm, there's seems to be an increment by 50 per 10 levels in the factor. Let's see - I haven't done this in a long time ....I feel 20 years younger already - I just left highschool ;-)

```
XP[level%10==0] = (level/10 + 1) * 50 * level
  = (level*50/10 + 50) * level
  = level*level*50/10 + 50*level
  = level*level*50/10 + (500*level/10)
  = level*level*50+500*level/10
  = level*level*50+500*level/10
  = level*(level*50+500)/10
  = level*(level*5+50)
```

put (both approaches: a) just adding to the previous XP b) calculate the XP for the mod10 levels) into code it looks like

```
<?php
$xp = 0;
for ( $level = 0; $level <= 100; $level++ ) {
    $xp_per_level = (ceil($level / 10) * 10) * 10;
    $xp += $xp_per_level;

    $calc_xp = $level*(($level*5)+50);
    if ( $level%10===0 ) {
        printf("Level %4d , XP: %6d,  calc: %6d\r\n", $level, $xp, $calc_xp);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Level    0 , XP:      0,  calc:      0
Level   10 , XP:   1000,  calc:   1000
Level   20 , XP:   3000,  calc:   3000
Level   30 , XP:   6000,  calc:   6000
Level   40 , XP:  10000,  calc:  10000
Level   50 , XP:  15000,  calc:  15000
Level   60 , XP:  21000,  calc:  21000
Level   70 , XP:  28000,  calc:  28000
Level   80 , XP:  36000,  calc:  36000
Level   90 , XP:  45000,  calc:  45000
Level  100 , XP:  55000,  calc:  55000
```

same values as in http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=457523080
You will notice that approach b) is only accurate for levels%10===0, e.g. for level 11 $calc_xp will be 1155 instead of 1200...
I'll leave that up to you. You can solve that almost exactly like the +10 steps.

Comment: I was very close! Beautifully and carefully explained, thank you very much for your help +1